# Buying AppleCare warranty in a different name than the original buyer's

Tags: applecare, warranty

A friend has the opportunity to get a recently purchased Apple MacBook from a colleague in exchange for some work.

It was very recently purchased (< 2 weeks). The receipt is in the original owner's name.

The new owner would like to purchase an AppleCare warranty for the machine in *their* name so there's no trouble in case they would ever need the warranty.

Is this possible?

Is it enough to simply purchase the AppleCare, fill in a form with the new owner's name, and thus connect it to the machine for warranty purposes?

Is it necessary to purchase AppleCare in the first place? Here in the EU, there is a mandatory 2-year warranty anyway. I guess my broader question is how Apple deals with changes of ownership for their products. Would one have to expect any trouble when making use of the warranty if the owner's name has changed?

Comment: I think it is but the best answer will simply come from Apple: http://www.apple.com/support

Comment: @nix fair point. I'll give it a shot and add here if I find anything out. (Mods, if this is of no value to the site even if answered, feel free to delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called Apple Support with just this question two years ago.  They seemed completely uninterested me showing that the machine had been properly transferred to me; my claim that I had it was good enough.  I bought AppleCare for a Macbook from Amazon.com and registered it with Apple received the final paperwork from them promptly, no further questions asked (this was in the US).

(FWIW, I did get a receipt and acknowledgment of the transfer of ownership to me from the seller in case it should ever become necessary, such as in an insurance claim).

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! Unless I get told otherwise by Apple support, I'll recommend they keep all receipts,  write a contract to make the transfer legit, and then just go ahead and try to register the AppleCare in the new name.

Comment: @Pekka: Enjoy your new Macbook!  BTW, getting (at least a copy of) the original receipts along with the transfer wouldn't be a bad idea as well.

Comment: thanks, but sadly, it's not for me! :) I hope to be getting myself one next year though. Yeah, keeping all the receipts is definitely a good idea, I will pass that on.

Comment: No need for papers. The warranty attaches to the serial number and not the person. If you ever need to take it in for service, they will update the records to show you as the owner. You can self register at apple.com/support if it makes you feel better.

Comment: @bmike: Apparently so, for AppleCare, but possibly useful someday for an insurance claim or proof of theft, should either become necessary, and for a little bit of assurance that I'm not buying a stolen machine (may not be relevant in the case of the OP's friend).